# Parsing a URL using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to parse an address from a string and have had partial success for select strings....

Currently I have

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[/].*[a-zA-Z](?=\/|:|)", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

On the input string `https://www.google.com/` the current pattern gets me `//www.google.com` (which is somewhat correct) however when I try the input string `https://www.google.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions&num=1000` it gives me `//www.google.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions&num`

What I am trying to do is parse the address so that it ends before `:`, `/`, or whitespace

I did also come up with

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[.*/][^/][a-z].*[a-zA-Z](?=\/|:|)", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

and it works (partially) with `https://google.com:80` giving me `/google.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use Java's [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)?

Comment: I could, however I'm trying to learn regex!

Comment: Ok, how about `.*?//[^:/\s]*`?

Comment: Big tip: use [Regex101](http://regex101.com). It'll help you learn _and_ it'll help you debug regular expressions. It's an invaluable tool.

Comment: Thanks for the website suggestion. I tried what you suggested schmosel, and it's getting the whole string rather than www.google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex [`^.*?\/\/([^:\/\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gdcCLd/2), the part you're searching is stored in group 1.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*?\\/\\/([^:\\/\\s]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("your input url");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Domain: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed the extra backslash issue by matching `//` before the expression.

Comment: This is working perfectly, minus the additional / which can be easily substringed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This revision of the answer by @NicolasMaltais should fix the extra `/` problem (I just show the first line of code):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*?\\/+([^:\\/\\s]+)");
```

This pattern will eat any number of `/` characters before the address. So, URLS like "file:///my_file.txt" can also be handled (if you only cared about the start of the file path).